# changing first excel worksheet and auto reference graphs

Tags: excel

[image: This is what the graphs look like]
This is what the graphs look like; the slicer is visible on the left and controls visible data.

I have a table that is used to generate many graphs on a separate worksheet and I'm using a slicer to filter what data is displayed on the graphs. All of the graphs are used to analyze every data set. The data sets all have the same format. Is there a way just to add the new data and have the graphs reference the first worksheet so that just changing the order updates the graphs?

Or maybe someone knows a better way to do this? I'm able to copy and paste new data into the first worksheet and the graphs update but the slice is then removed. Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use macros! 
Start by recording the macro and then modify the script to meet your needs accordingly. I was able to table the csv, create a new worksheet, and graph all the data as well as add and resize the slicer. By changing a few variable names this macro can now be applied to all base worksheets.